# How to resize content of Ionic grid to a fixed height without scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, grid

I'm trying to create a grid of columns and rows using the Ionic Framework.
My goal is IonGrid taking the remaining available height while displaying the entire content without having to scroll to reveal hidden content outside the viewport. The content (columns & rows) must therefore resize in order to show everything at once. This must result in everything being very small, but at least it is there for the viewing.

I'm using React v18.2.0 and Ionic/React v7.0.0

and here is a terrible paint job illustrating my issue. The last row is cut off with the green part being outside the viewport requiring the user to scroll in order to reveal it. The entire grid must therefore fit on the available space, but resize to do so.
[image]

Here is an example of my current component:

```
        <IonContent>
        <IonGrid>
            <IonRow>
                <IonCol size="4">
                    <IonRow>
                        ... content
                    </IonRow>
                    <IonRow>
                        ... content
                    </IonRow>
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol size="4">
                    <IonRow>
                        ... content
                    </IonRow>
                    <IonRow>
                        ... content
                    </IonRow>
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol size="4">
                    <IonRow>
                        ... content
                    </IonRow>
                    <IonRow>
                        ... content
                    </IonRow>
                </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
            <IonRow>
                <IonCol size="12">
                    ... content
                </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
    </IonContent>
```

I tried experimenting with setting the maxHeight, height, overflow on both the IonContent and IonGrid without any luck. I'm aware of the scrollY prop of IonGrid, and setting it to *false* does prevent any scrolling from being possible. However, then the rest of the content within the IonGrid is hidden further down the page without the chance of seeing it.

Is it possible to customize the IonGrid to solve this while also having a responsive system or am I best off doing this with regular CSS?

Comment: your best off using regular css.

Comment: I'm not the greatest at writing plain CSS that is responsive for the different screen sizes. Would something like Bootstrap for React be better you think? I'm aware that generally the ideology of Bootstrap does not fit React, but there is a library nonetheless.

Comment: Then this will be a great time to practice your css then! You should not be mixing 2 different libraries, the designs have inconsistencies that your users will see and give off a bad user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the entire grid fit on the available space, but also resize you can set `display: grid` and `height` css property on `ion-grid`.

I have created a sample of what you need. Check the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64dqr3?file=src/main.tsx

`CSS`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ion-grid {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
}
ion-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;

  background-color: #135d54;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time writing up a great example.
Your solution does solve my problem, so I will mark your solution. However, as soon as the IonGrid is wrapped in an IonContent, or I re-activate IonHeader/IonFooter then the scrollbar reappears on the grid.
So I'm guessing that the 100vh grants the grid too much of the height as the top and bottom is used by the Header and Footer.
Would this require a calculation for the height on ion-grid?

Comment: Instead of using `100vh` on `ion-grid` use `100%`. This makes the grid only to take the available space. I have added the header and footer in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64dqr3-g7a5of?file=src/App.tsx. Now the grid taking only the availabe space. So the scrollbar doesn't appears now.

Comment: Ah of course. Your example works pretty good without IonContent, as using IonContent as a wrapper creates a scrollbar. I did try setting the height of the IonContent to 100% as well, but no luck. Removing the IonContent works great with the Header and Footer.
Also, the `display: flex` on ion-col makes the rows within that column appear of the same line while the desired outcome is having them above each other one-by-one. Trying different `display` values for the ion-col does result in the rows appearing above each other but then the scrollbar appears once more.